# Find an item in JSon File using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to know how heavy it is to filter a huge data set.

I have huge dataset contains "Polygones" and "Points". I am looking for a point everytime in this dataset. 
In case of point, I use equality.
In case of polygone, I see whether point belongs to the polygone or no.

```
var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [[
                [13.37356, 52.52064],
                [13.37350, 52.51971],
                [13.37664, 52.51973],
                [13.37594, 52.52062],
                [13.37356, 52.52064]
            ]]
        },
        "properties": {
            "height": 500
        }
    },{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [13.37356, 52.52064]
        },
        "properties": {
            "height": 500
        }
    }]
};
```

I wrote those two functions :

```
function isPointinJsonFile(point,data) {

  for (var i = data.features.length; i >= 0; i--) {  
      console.log(data.features[i].geometry.type)
     if(data.features[i].geometry.type= "point"){
      console.log(point)
     return (data.features[i].geometry.coordinates == point)
    }
     if(data.features[i].geometry.type= "MultiPolygon"){
    return isPointInPoly(data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][0],point)
    }
}};


function isPointInPoly(poly, pt){
            for(var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
                ((poly[i][1] <= pt[1] && pt[1] < poly[j][1]) || (poly[j][1] <= pt[1] && pt[1] < poly[i][1]))
                && (pt[0]< (poly[j][0] - poly[i][0]) * (pt.y - poly[i][1]) / (poly[j][1] - poly[i][1]) + poly[i][0])
                && (c = !c);
            { console.log(poly)
              return c;  }
    }
```

inspire by: http://jsfromhell.com/math/is-point-in-poly

But I ended up having no point.
- Is there any function in JavaScrip that makes the equality with error rate. 
like taking only first number after the point ex:instead of comparing 13, 37457234 we compare 13,3 
- Is what I am doing right ??

Comment: you have errors in both your `if` statements (you have assignments not equality tests).

Comment: Try checking your code in [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) first, I get a bunch of warnings, that `for` loop doesn't look right, what's going on there?

Comment: Check now ! I ve just updated it. The part where you get warnings, I ve worked on an example that I found it here. http://jsfromhell.com/math/is-point-in-poly